# After the migration of antd from 2.0 -> 3.0 the default font size got increased from 12px -> 14px , is there a way to customize the antd fontsize?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux, antd

Cannot change the default font-size of antd table from 14px to 12px after the migration of antd 2.0 -> 3.0 .Can somebody help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

You can either:

Use the v2 styling `import 'antd/lib/style/v2-compatible-reset';`

or

Manually adjust the font with `modifyvar` to overwrite these LESS variables:

```
@font-size-base         : 14px;
@font-size-lg           : @font-size-base + 2px;
@font-size-sm           : 12px;
```

more info

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less

Comment: Same issue here, if I'm using SCSS, how could I override these values? Do I need to explode the whole antd styling from its npm module to change this?

Comment: do you mean scss on your project? it would be the same with modifyvar. the input modifyvar takes a json file. eg. `"theme": {
  "primary-color": "#1DA57A",
},`

Comment: I got it work, I had to compile with less and then reference the compiled css.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I would share the method I took, as it is a bit different, I use SASS in my project so a pure less approach was tricky. Instead, I copied the dist and lib folders to a new directory, I then edited the font size variables in:

`lib/style/themes/default.less`

Then I installed less, and then ran from the `dist`folder

`lessc antd.less antdcompiled.css`

I then copied this file into my project, referenced it, and it worked well.